# Text Overlapping Image with Relative Position in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to make my text overlap over this image in relative position, while also staying in the 100vmin boundaries. Here is my HTML code. I know the image won't show on Stack Overflow, but the image is an SVG file. The SVG is an exact sqaure, being 332 in width and height in the SVG file(as a txt file).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created and Copyright of MrEthanVlogsandGames -->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/images/tab_icon.svg">
        <style>
            /******
            FONTS
            ******/
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

            /******
            EVERYTHING ELSE
            ******/

            body {
                font-family: Roboto;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                background-color: #000;
            }
            ul {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .app {
                width: 100vmin;
                height: 100vmin;
            }
            .starting_page > img {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            p.text {
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 2;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <div class="starting_page">
                <img src="/images/starting_page.svg">
                <p class="text">Overlapping Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `position: relative` needs to be on parent element, then you use `position: absolute` on the element you want to overlap and position them within the `relative` parent using `top` `left` etc.

Technically you can move an element around with `position: relative` and `top` `left` etc but the problem is that it'll still take up space in it's original position. Above method doesn't have this problem.

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000;
}

.app {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
}

.starting_page>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

p.text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="starting_page">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/332">
    <p class="text">Overlapping Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```